# How can I detect width and height of the webcamera?

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

**How can I detect width and height of the camera to use it on canvas and maintain the proportions??**

I need to detect width and height of the camera and then use it on a canvas. In the new canvas I will show the live video with some filters. The size of the camera should be the same as the video.

The code I use to get access to the camera:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = (navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || naviagor.msGetUserMedia);

    var options = {video: true};
    var videoWidth, videoHeight;

    var onFail = function(e) {
      alert('Failed to get camera');
      alert(e);
    };
    var onSuccess = function(stream) {

        if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) {
            video.mozSrcObject = stream;
        } else {
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            video.src = url.createObjectURL(stream);
        }

        // Wait 1000 ms before starting the loop
        setTimeout(function(){

            //rest of functions ...
            //Here I need to use: videoWidth, videoHeight
            //that are obtained from the image data of the camera

        },1000);
    };

    navigator.getUserMedia(options, onSuccess, onFail);
```

Comment: You can set the video constraints in your options like video: { width: 1280, height: 720 }..check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia

Comment: Or something like: videoWidth = video.videoWidth;
    videoHeight = video.videoHeight;

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There are two ways: Chrome and Firefox support the new [`track.getSettings()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/getSettings):

```
let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
let {width, height} = stream.getTracks()[0].getSettings();
console.log(`${width}x${height}`); // 640x480
```

This works regardless of whether the stream is hooked up to anything.

Alternatively, for older browsers, hook the stream up to a [video element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLVideoElement), and (importantly) [wait for metadata to load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadedmetadata), before looking at `videoWidth` and `videoHeight`:

```
video.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true});
await new Promise(resolve => video.onloadedmetadata = resolve);
console.log(`${video.videoWidth}x${video.videoHeight}`); // 640x480
```

Note that most web cams support more than one resolution. Use [constraints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Parameters) for higher resolution:

```
await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {width: 9999}}); // 1280x720
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/3hksbngx/).

Answer (score 3):

You can get width and height by using `videoWidth` and `videoHeight` properties of `video` element:

```
video.videoWidth
video.videoWidth
```

Check [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L6ago1m6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

7yrs later

streams can consist of multiple tracks, audio, media, video
so it's important that you iterate and see which one is a video and take the size from that track.

```js
let width, height;
stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
  if (track.kind === 'video') {
    width = track.getSettings().width;
    height = track.getSettings().height;
  }
});
```